# com.android.support:customtabs: No virtual method launchUrl

Tags: android, chrome-custom-tabs

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method launchUrl(Landroid/app/Activity;Landroid/net/Uri;)V in class Landroid/support/customtabs/CustomTabsIntent
```

Before everything worked, but today I can see the above error.
Why it happens? if something was changed, why not backwards-compatible?

Comment: Could you post the support library version you are using and, if possible, the section of code that is launching the Custom Tabs?

Comment: latest version, latest code from official github sample app

Comment: Are you getting the error on this line? https://github.com/GoogleChrome/custom-tabs-client/blob/master/Application/src/main/java/org/chromium/customtabsclient/MainActivity.java#L191

Answer (score 16):

Don't know if it helps you but in my case (I have Facebook SDK in my app with [custom tabs enabled](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android#chrome_custom_tabs)) this error happened when user (without installed Facebook app) tried to log in.

```
Exception java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method launchUrl(Landroid/app/Activity;Landroid/net/Uri;)V in class Landroid/support/customtabs/CustomTabsIntent; or its super classes 
com.facebook.internal.CustomTab.openCustomTab (CustomTab.java:48)
```

Updating dependency to use latest SDK version (they switched to customtabs:25.0.0 in version 4.17.0)

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.17.0'
```

fixed the problem.

I also use Custom Tabs (v25.0.0) in my app and have no issues with them. If it's not your case [you can check what they've changed](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/commits/master).

Comment: This is still an issue with the following dependencies : `compile "com.android.support:customtabs:25.0.1"` and `compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.19.0'`

Comment: Looks like the issue is documented here as well https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues/398